# How to mock a method with functional arguments in Scala?

Tags: scala, mocking

I'm trying to mock a method call that takes a call-by-name argument:

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

trait Collaborator {
   def doSomething(t: => Thing)
}

trait Thing

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class Test extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
   "The subject under test" should {
      "call the collaborator" in {
         // setup
         val m = mock[Collaborator]
         val t = mock[Thing]

         // test code: this would actually be invoked by the SUT
         m.doSomething(t)

         // verify the call
         verify(m).doSomething(t)
      }
   }
}
```

I'm primarily interested in Mockito since that's what I'm using, but I'd be interested to see whether any of the major mock frameworks is capable of this kind of testing.  The Test fails at runtime on the `verify` line, with an error like

> ```
> Argument(s) are different! Wanted:  
> collaborator.doSomething(  
>    ($anonfun$apply$3) <function>  
> );  
> -> at Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Test.scala:27)  
> Actual invocation has different arguments:  
> collaborator.doSomething(  
>     ($anonfun$apply$2) <function>  
> );  
> -> at Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Test.scala:24)
> ```

If I'm understanding the situation correctly, the compiler is implicitly wrapping `t` in a nullary function that returns `t`. The mock framework is then comparing that function to the one produced in the test code, which is equivalent but not `equals()`.

My case is a relatively simple version of the problem, but I think this would be an issue with any higher-order function.

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to the Apple iPad.

Comment: Could you describe how it doesn't work more clearly or include some test code. It's hard to know what's going on here with just the verify shown.

Comment: I made the example runnable as written and included the actual output associated with the failure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks ugly, but hopefully it can help you to find good solution:

```
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito._

trait Collaborator {
   def doSomething(t: => Thing)
}

trait Thing

new MockitoSugar {
     // setup
     val m = mock[Collaborator]
     val t = mock[Thing]

     m.doSomething(t)

     classOf[Collaborator].getMethod("doSomething", classOf[Function0[_]]).invoke(
        verify(m), 
        new Function0[Thing] { 
            def apply() = null
            override def equals(o: Any): Boolean = t == o.asInstanceOf[Function0[Thing]].apply() 
      })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Byname). In specs2, we "hijack" the Mockito `Invocation` class to account for byname parameters:

```
trait ByName { def call(i: =>Int) = i }
val byname = mock[ByName]

byname.call(10)
there was one(byname).call(10)
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I copied that snippet into a new Play 2.2.3 app spec and it still fails. I'm using a simple `mutable.Specification with Mockito` test class, `specs2_2.10-2.1.1` and `mockito-core-1.9.5` (declared explicitly in `build.sbt`, making sure specs2 is declared before mockito) Any clue why it still fails?

Comment: You need to make sure that the specs2 jar comes before the Mockito jar on the classpath.

Comment: Any hint how to that with SBT? I already tried changing declaration order.

Comment: That's how I'm doing and it usually works. One thing you can try is to depend on specs2-core and specs2-mock without depending on mockito because specs2-mock will drag it for you and hopefully the order will be right.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be specific to by-name invocations because in regular higher order functions you can match against the explicit FunctionX object:

verify(collaborator).somethingElse(any(Function2[String, Thing]))

in the by-name case the wrapping of the argument into a Function0 is done implicitly, and Alexey's answer shows how to invoke the mock with an explicit parameter.

You could write something akin to your own verify which would apply arguments captured by mockito.

Mockito internally records invocation and their arguments with e.g.:
http://code.google.com/p/mockito/source/browse/trunk/src/org/mockito/internal/matchers/CapturingMatcher.java

Comment: This does not work, as the function expects a single call-by-name parameter of type Thing (: => Thing), which is not the same type as Function2[String, Thing] (:String => Thing). There needs to be a higher-kinded type for typing call-by-name parameters in order to use matchers.