# mock a function with a callback function as parameter

Tags: scala, callback, easymock

My code structure is like below:

```
class A {
  def a(x: () => Unit) { do something}
}

class B {
  .... 
  def foo() {
    def x() { something }
    a(x)
  }
}
```

Now I want to do unittest of class B with a mock A.

```
val a = mock[A]
def x () { ... }
a.a(x) atLeastOnce
```

The above doesn't work. Since this new x is not the x inside foo().  But the x inside foo is a local one, not accessible to unittest. Any suggestion except to move x out of foo?

Comment: I do want to test B. A is an external class relying on DB -- means I have to mock A in the unittest. Since A.a needs a callback function as its parameter, I wrote x().

Comment: It sounds like you want to express that `A.a` is called at least once, but you don't care about the parameter that is used in the call. I don't know EasyMock, but mocking frameworks usually express such expectations with something like `a.a(any) atLeastOnce`.  If you *do* care about the closure (e.g. you want to verify that it has a particular side-effect), you could capture the actual argument and invoke it (to fake `A`'s role).

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock out the function literal passed into A.a. Please look into the answer of the following SOF question and see whether that helps

[How to mock a method with functional arguments in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152019/how-to-mock-a-method-with-functional-arguments-in-scala)