# Is there a way to match on a call-by-name argument of a Mockito mock object in Specs?

Tags: scala, specs

I am testing the interaction between one object, and another object with some methods that have *call-by-name* arguments. However, I can't figure out how to create an argument matcher for that call-by-name argument.

Let's say that this is the signature of the mocked object:

`def fn(arg1: => String, arg2: Int): Any`

Then what I really want to do is test if that method is called with a known second argument. I don't even care all that much about the first argument, but having a way to properly test that as well would be a bonus.

This doesn't work:

`there was one(mock) fn(any[()=>String], eq(12))`

nor this:

`there was one(mock) fn(any[Function0[String]], eq(12))`

and this doesn't even compile:

`there was one(mock) fn(any[=>String], eq(12))`

... which obviously is to be expected.

Comment: I don't know anything about Mockito, but have you tried `any[String]`?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152019/how-to-mock-a-method-with-functional-arguments-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added some support in specs2 for [byname arguments and functions/partial function arguments](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/X9OMF64XwKg/ow1A3NjXki0J). Please try out the latest specs2-1.9-SNAPSHOT and create an issue on GitHub if that doesn't work for you.