# Mocking a function with pass-by-name arguments

Tags: scala, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

My actual use-case is unit testing code involving finagle `FuturePool`: I want to make sure, `FuturePool.apply` was actually invoked, so that the task was executed in the correct instance of the pool.

The problem I am running into however seems more generic, so I will illustrate it on an abstract example, not related to finagle or futures.

Suppose, I have these two classes:

```
    class Foo {
      def apply(f: => String) = f
    }

    class Bar(val foo: Foo) {
      def doit(f: => String) = foo(f)
    }
```

`Bar` has an instance of `Foo`, that knows how to run functions, and I want to test that it is actually using it for execution:

```
    describe("Bar") {
      it("should use the right foo") {
        val foo = mock[Foo]
        when(foo.apply(any)).thenAnswer( new Answer[String] {
          def answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock): String =
            invocation.getArgumentAt(0, classOf[Function0[String]]).apply()
        })
        new Bar(foo).doit("foo") should equal("foo")
      }
    }
```

This does not work: `.doit` return null, apparently, because mockito does not realize it was mocked. It seems that `any` is not matching `Function0` in this case (replacing it with `any[Function0[String]]` does not help either.

I also tried it another way:

```
it("should Foo!") {
    val foo = Mockito.spy(new Foo)
    new Bar(foo).doit("foo") should equal("foo")
    verify(foo).apply(any)
  }
```

This also does not work, and kinda confirms my suspicion about `any` not working in this case:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
foo$1.apply(
    ($anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$7) <function0>
);
Actual invocation has different arguments:
foo$1.apply(
    ($anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$6) <function0>
);
```

Any ideas about a good way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This signature:

```
def apply(f: => String)
```

is known as "call by name" where it passes an expression instead of an evaluated expression.  This is very specific to Scala and not well supported with Mockito.

There is a host of workarounds to this:

- [Is there a way to match on a call-by-name argument of a Mockito mock object in Specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512234/is-there-a-way-to-match-on-a-call-by-name-argument-of-a-mockito-mock-object-in-s)
- [How to mock a method with functional arguments in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152019/how-to-mock-a-method-with-functional-arguments-in-scala)
- [How do you mock scala call-by name in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487537/how-do-you-mock-scala-call-by-name-in-mockito)

The [one by Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889153/722180) looks the simplest and what you may want.

Comment: I cannot change the definition of the method on the library class I am mocking ...